# Reading the resource directory inside a Jar file

Tags: java, jar, reference

I have tried a lot of searches over the past couple of days, but the issue remains unresolved, and hence putting the question here. Appologies to those who think it is answered elsewhere.

I have a program in a jar file, mymainprogram.jar which references another jar file called, reference.jar

mymainprogram.jar 
|_ myMainClass.class

|_ otherclass1.class

|_ otherclass2.class

|_ reference.jar
|_ reference1.class
|_ reference2.class
|_ resources/folder1/folder2/image001.jpeg
|_ resources/folder1/folder2/image002.jpeg
|_ resources/folder1/folder2/image003.jpeg
.....

|_ resources/folder1/folder2/image099.jpeg

The class reference2.class requires to read the resources from the /resources folder for it to execute its functionality.

myMainClass.class at run time calls reference2.class, which has to read the resources.. When running inside eclipse, as a part of the project it works fine. However, when working as standalone jars,
reference1.getClass().getResource("/resources/folder/folder2") returns null.

Basically i want to get the File object to folder2, and then read the file listing at runtime, when contained inside the jar. Other, This fails by returning null all the time.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: You can't read a Jar that was in Java 6 or before. You need to list all the files in the JAR and find the ones with match your directory.  In Java 7 you can use the JAR like a file system, but I haven't used that API.

Comment: Have you checked the CLASSPATH and META-INF to make sure they are set correctly?